# How to handle JMESPath contains filter on attribute that may be null?

Tags: shell, azure, null, filtering, jmespath

I want to filter the output from the Azure CloudShell command [az ad sp list](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-ca/cli/azure/ad/sp?view=azure-cli-latest#az-ad-sp-list) which outputs a JSON array, eg by filtering to Publisher Name = "ACME". All az commands support a --query argument which accepts a JMESPath expression.

I have a JMESPath filter:

```
az ad sp list --query "[?contains(publisherName,'ACME')]" --all
```

that fails with error:

```
In function contains(), invalid type for value: None, expected one of: ['array', 'string'], received: "null"
```

I'm confident of my JMESPath syntax since a very similar expression works correctly:

```
az ad sp list --query "[?contains(displayName,'ACME')]" --all
```

I have a null filter that works fine:

```
az ad sp list --query "[?publisherName!='null']" --all
```

But when I combine the null filter with the contains filter I still get the error:

```
az ad sp list --query "[?publisherName!='null' && contains(publisherName,'ACME')]" --all
```

I'm guessing that JMESPath filter doesn't support [boolean operations short circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). However I didn't find any statement about that on http://jmespath.org/ or by googling.

I don't know how to daisy chain or pipe with the Azure az command --query clause to apply the two filters separately.

Any suggestion how to achieve my filtered output?

Comment: The error indicates you have a problem with your jmespath query syntax. It says "invalid type for value" in the contains() function.

Answer (score 15):

### Context

- MSFT azure cloud shell console (as of 2019-11-17)
- azure cloud shell `az` commands with jmespath query
- jmespath handling of potentially-null values in a filter-expression

### Use-case

- [UserJohnCDeveloper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/815175/johnc) wants to run a JMESPath filter on attributes that may be null
- how to daisy chain or pipe with the Azure `az command --query` clause

### Solution

- Jmespath support for [pipe expressions](http://jmespath.org/proposals/pipes.html)
- Jmespath supports passing the result of one expression to another, though use of pipe expressions. This enables queries of arbitrary complexity through chaining together of multiple sub-expressions and filters.

### Example

```
 --query "[? publisherName!=null]|[? contains(publisherName,'ACME')]" --all
```

Answer (score 14):

The not_null function comes handy. It keeps the intent of the query more readable.

```
az ad sp list --query "[?contains(not_null(publisherName,''),'ACME')]" --all
```

The function returns the first non-null argument. This is often called "coalesce" elsewhere.

Answer (score -1):

For those looking for a more general approach, use `||` to create an or-expression:

```
expression || expression
```

[Ref jmespath.org](https://jmespath.org/proposals/pipes.html#modified-grammar)